# Product name in Magento order confirmation email subject

Tags: magento-1.9, php, email-templates

(Magento 1)

I'd like to add the name of the product in the order confirmation email subject. How do I do that?

Comment: What if there's more than one item in the order?

Comment: In that case we can add the quantity. Suppose there are 3 items, then subject would be like this: Your order for XYZ Phone & 2 others has been received!